# Proper way of Link generation from string

Tags: 8

How can I generate a link in a proper way in Drupal 8? I have a field where the user can say an internal or external page/website.

Internal:
/node/6
/articles
/articles#Subheading
etc.

External:
www.google.com
//www.google.com
https://www.google.com

How can I transform these into a link with the following condition:
the site root is: www.mydomain.com/mysite/
internal links should have language versions: i.e. en/articles or pt/articles .

I've tried with `Link::fromTextAndUrl('My link', Url::fromUri('internal:/articles'))`, but this requires a URI which is not my goal and it doesn't follow the selected user language.

Comment: Why aren't you using core link field?

Comment: This data is saved into config. (as a module's config)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `internal:/` you just need to have some help text that says an internal path should begin with a slash.

After that, when you create the links, you can do:

```
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\UrlHelper;

....
....
....

function or method.... {
  $path = // get config value
  $label = // get config value

  if (UrlHelper::isExternal($path)) {
    $url = Url::fromUri($path);
  } else {
    $url = Url::fromUserInput($path);
  }

  return Link::fromTextAndUrl($label, $url);
}
```

Of course I am assuming there is always a value... you'd have to add your own checks so you don't get errors calling `Url::` for null or empty input, etc.

The return will be an renderable array to use. I am using a similar method to allow input for third party settings on a config entity. This way the value can be internal or external.

Comment: I don't know why but this does not follow the selected site language. I hope not because I'm using the `Link::fromTextAndUrl(..., ...)->toString()` function...

Comment: I don't work with languages much, but it seems like either the link needs to have the langcode in it: https://www.drupal.org/project/language_hierarchy/issues/3088151  but there appears to be a core issue as well https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2924653

Comment: Well, the interesting part is if I generate it from the route it has language code in the URL. But from a string, it's not really want to generate a language code in it... which is a problem. Another interesting thing, if I use node/nid then there will be language code in the URL, but it won't be alias... If I use the alias, then there won't be language code in the URL...

Comment: Actually it worked fine, but I didn't have some translation for some languages and that's why I had problems, between reality and the expectations...